# Why does my app close on first open but then works after?

Tags: android

I will run my code on an emulator and the app will open. After pressing a button to go to Google Maps, the map tries to load but then the app crashes and says "Open app again?" Once I reopen the app, and press the button a second time, it seems like most of the time not always the map is able to load, and the app works perfectly.

Are there any key words I should look for in my logcat? I am only familiar with the red text when my code absolutely doesn't work, so I'm not sure what to look for.

Lastly, my "object.setMyLocationEnabled(true)" doesn't show up with a blue dot on Google Maps, but literally one time it did.

TL;DR I'm not changing my code, but why does it randomly do whatever it want? Does it compile differently each time or something?

Comment: post the logcat when your app crashed.

Comment: ...and also post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I'd personally add a try catch around everything after setContentView() and then log the exception.
Use:

```
Log.e("Exception caught: ", e.getMessage());
```

Then if the exception doesn't make sense, use breakpoints and run in debug to see where the exception is thrown.

Please post the exception you get if you are still having trouble.